# iOS - Disable UIDocumentInteractionController options button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Quick question.  Does anyone know if there is a way you can disable the UIDocumentInteractionController from presenting the menu to open the document in a different application? (The button in the top right) Or at least hide that button?  I thought I remembered seeing that you could do that somewhere....

ie.  Is there like a `docController.menuButton.hidden = YES` or something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look at a Quick Look controller, not a UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: Using a `QLPreviewController` doesn't make it much easier https://stackoverflow.com/a/69454052/1049134

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial and may break with every iOS update.

First you'll need to get the underlying `QLPreviewController` that is created by the `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

For that implement `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`'s `documentInteractionControllerWillBeginPreview`:

```
public func documentInteractionControllerWillBeginPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // Use async or you won't get anything
        let aQLPreviewController = self.documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller).presentedViewController

        // Next dig the QLPreviewController hierarchy
    }
}
```

Now that you have the underlaying `QLPreviewController` follow the instructions from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69454052/1049134