# How to Subclass QLPreviewController and Disable Share button?

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

- I have done code like this but it's open QLPreviewController but
  Share button was not disabled. I have tried different things but it's
  not worked.

  **- Or You Can Suggest me any different Preview Controller in which i can Disable Share button.**
- qlViewController = QLPreviewController()
- qlViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
- qlViewController.delegate = self
- qlViewController.dataSource = self

func numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController(controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

```
func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    return fileUrlToOpen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on iOS 15, may change with next updates.

`QLPreviewController` now embeds a `UINavigationController` which then has a root controller with a standard `navigationItem` that we can tweak.

```
guard let navigationItem = (aQLPreviewController.children.first as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first?.navigationItem else
{
    // Not iOS 15 or the QLPreviewController implementation has changed
    return
}

// Do whatever you want with the navigationItem
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
// or navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

Answer (score -1):

UPD: This DOESN'T work anymore

There is an example of how to hide the right share button

```
final class AttachmentQuickLookVC: QLPreviewController {
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()        
    }
}
```

Also, u can do something like this if u want to customize back button:

```
final class AttachmentQuickLookVC: QLPreviewController {
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()        
        let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 35))
        
        backButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        backButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_back"), for: .normal)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButton]
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me. Button still shows up top right.

Comment: @zumzum well, it worked at the moment of post. So, if system changed, and u found updated solution, please provide it.

Comment: It is no longer possible to modify `QLPreviewController`s navigation items at all